# Cant perform touch-up inside action for a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a button in my interface builder (using nibs by the way), i  control dragged from the button to the view controller .h file and called it "cancelReminder" (and set it to be action):

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *homeLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;

- (IBAction)cancelReminder:(id)sender;

@end
```

this created me a method in the .m file, and I just nslog'd something there that says "cancel" to test it.

In the interface builder I controlled dragged from the button to the files owner to make sure its connected to the method "cancelReminder".

this should perform it right?? its not.

something important to mention: the cancel button is a child of a view, and this view is a child of the main view.

this looks like that:

[image]

I know I shouldnt do this but just for testing the behaviour if I control drag from the cancel button to the file owner and select view, when i run the app, i see black screen and i can see the button and its working...by working i mean the method is responding:

[image]

I took it back, i tried it so maybe someone counld understand from this behaviour what is happening.

please please help me figure this out :/// it happened before :(

thannks a bunch!!

my viewDiLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.slidingView.hidden = YES;
    // black BG to make the background darker when the reminder view is sliding in
    self.reminderBG.hidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.homeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:40];
    self.homeLabel.text = stackTableViewController.currentTarget;
    self.homeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.homeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.myScrollView.delegate = self;

    //setting up the button bounds
    self.buttonBounds = self.createButton.bounds;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapResponder)];

    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired =1;
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

    [self.homeLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

and my action sheet method that slides the reminderView in:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        self.reminderBG.hidden = NO;
        self.slidingView.hidden = NO;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        self.slidingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,20);
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The outlet names in your .xib and file owner do not add up, see your own screenshots - ScrollView: [Group1, done button etc.], ReminderView and the ones that show up when you drag to your file owner - createButton, slidingView, view. Are you sure that you have correct class (HomeViewController) set in the File's Owner attributes inspector?

Comment: @Woodstock sure, tell me what do you need to see and I will upload it

Comment: @Eugene yes bro, its because I change it after

Comment: @Woodstock iv tried to delete the buttons and set just one up for testing, still not working, I think the issue is something to do with the fact that the button is a child of the reminderView and something need to be set up there and I dont know what...

Comment: Can you see if "User Interaction Enabled" field on ReminderView is checked?

Comment: Also can you try to connect buttons that are not on the reminderView? Just to be sure that the problem with this particular view?

Comment: @VladimirK hi man, the user interaction on reminderView is checked, something else to mention is that I have a UIImageView that is covering the reminderView....and on that image view I have the button

Comment: @Eugene please see the comment above, maybe this info will help you understand something

Comment: @VladimirK i have buttons on the main view and they work perfect, i dont know what is wrong here :(

Comment: Try to enable "User Interaction Enabled" for UIImageView.

Comment: @VladimirK i was just about to write you that I tried it and its not working :)

Comment: I see. A lot of things could be a cause of this problem. Do you use UIGestureRecognizer in this view controller?

Comment: Make sure that the button is on top of all UI elements on this view. Maybe you adding something from the code on top of the reminderView?

Comment: @VladimirK I do use uigesture in this view contoller

Comment: Try to comment the code where you adding the gesture recognizer, and let me know if problem remains.

Comment: @VladimirK i added my viewdidload and my action sheet method, please see my edit

Comment: @VladimirK i guess you right and there is something on top of it in code, let e know if you see it

Comment: Try to remove line of code - [self.homeLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer]; and let me know if problem disappears.

Comment: @VladimirK i want to comment it but the tap is something that triggers the action sheet and this is where i bring up the reminder view

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer now how you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be caused by gesture recognizer. Try to add delegate after creating tapRecognizer:

```
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

And use delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: and where am I calling gestureRecognizer: ? i tried it like this and nothing happeneds

Comment: Also add the delegate to @interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

Comment: so to be clear, under the line in view did load     tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
 i added tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
and the method just somewhere in the .m file

Comment: self.slidingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,20); - you setting height 20. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Set height value the same as in xib file

Comment: iv tried to set it 284 like in the xib         self.slidingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,284);, didnt work

Comment: it will probably something so stupid in the end i will slap myself

Comment: And what is the frame of the cancelButton?

Comment: w:46 h:30 x:137 y:239

Comment: there is also a date picker on the slidingview, i added a picture

Comment: Just to be sure - set background color of containerView to red, and background color of the button to blue, and see if the button inside the bounds of container after animation.

Comment: how can i set a button bg color? is there a property for that?

Comment: but on a button Background is an image, in the interfacebuilder i have text color and shadow color

Comment: Just scroll down, it's below

Comment: I’m without ideas now. You can try to move slidingView to front in case if something covers it:
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.slidingView];
You can do it right after animation.

Also try it with button:
[self.slidingView bringSubviewToFront:self.cancelView];